# Decision making inside a for loop and taking certain path based on output from gathered results

Tags: go

I would love to simplify my code, with better utilisation of for loop indexes. The goal is to change out all `UP` once for new `UP` once, which means take down each `UP` one and bring it up again. There should always be one in `UP` state while this process takes place, so I need to cover the following scenarios:

> up - up     == delete -> create -> delete -> create
>
> down - down == delete -> create -> delete -> create
>
> up - down   == delete -> create -> delete -> create
>
> down - up   == delete -> create -> delete -> create
>
> up          == create -> delete -> create
>
> down        == create -> delete -> create

This is what I have come up with, but I find it a bit cumbersome, and I', sure there is a room for an improvement.
For Instance could I go without using slices for holding the indexes `countStateAvailable` and `countStateDown`

```
fun myFunc() {
    var countStateAvailable []int
    var countStateDown []int
    lags := convertToDirectconnect(lagPair, amz.dcLags)
    vi := newVIFProvider(amz.dcRead, amz.dcWrite, bd, amz.trace, amz.pr)
    for i := 0; i < len(lags); i++ {
        if i == 0 {
            for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
                vis, err := amz.dcRead.DescribeVirtualInterfaces(&directconnect.DescribeVirtualInterfacesInput{ConnectionId: lags[j].LagId})
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                for k := 0; k < len(vis.VirtualInterfaces); k++ {
                    if *vis.VirtualInterfaces[k].OwnerAccount == cfg.RemoteAccountID {
                        if aws.StringValue(vis.VirtualInterfaces[k].VirtualInterfaceState) == directconnect.VirtualInterfaceStateAvailable {
                            countStateAvailable = append(countStateAvailable, j)
                        } else if aws.StringValue(vis.VirtualInterfaces[k].VirtualInterfaceState) == directconnect.VirtualInterfaceStateDown {
                            countStateDown = append(countStateDown, j)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if len(countStateAvailable) == 0 {
            fmt.Println("contains 1 or more down elements")
            err := amz.Create(cfg, nst)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }

        // check if second or both elements are UP
        if countStateAvailable[0] == 1  || len(countStateAvailable) == 2 {
            fmt.Println("second or both elements are UP")
            err = vi.DeleteSingle(cfg, lags[i], i)
            cfg.Neighbors, err = vi.CreateSingle(cfg, lags[i], i)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = vi.RestorePollSingle(cfg, lags[i], i)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else if countStateAvailable[0] == 0 { // first element is UP, delete second element first
            fmt.Println("first element is UP, delete second element first")
            err = vi.DeleteSingle(cfg, lags[1], 1)
            cfg.Neighbors, err = vi.CreateSingle(cfg, lags[1], 1)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = vi.RestorePollSingle(cfg, lags[1], 1)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            err = vi.DeleteSingle(cfg, lags[0], 0)
            cfg.Neighbors, err = vi.CreateSingle(cfg, lags[0], 0)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = vi.RestorePollSingle(cfg, lags[0], 0)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        } else {
            fmt.Println("contains 1 or more down elements")
            err := amz.Create(cfg, nst)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("countStateAvailable: ", countStateAvailable)
    fmt.Println("countStateDown: ", countStateDown)

    return nil
}
```